# Calculator using an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a button a textbox and a label. when the button is clicked, it should compute for the value in the textbox and output it on the label. My main problem is how to split the string so that when I typed `"12+12"` it would split it into `"12"` and `"12"` then compute the answer.

The approach I've done so far is to split all the text into characters.

```
char[] x;


for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.TextLength; i++) {
    x = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
    if (x[i].ToString() != "+")
    { 
    } else { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: string.Split("+");  maybe.....

Comment: ok, reading how to use string.split() now. im a total newb on c#. thanks!

Comment: Can you have more than 2 operands (like 12+12-7)?  Is order of operations important?

Comment: @Tim not really. though i might put ordering into it. just practising my arraysxD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do this to plus, and please do check first:

```
string str = yourTextBoxValue.Text;
string[] strs = str.Split(new char[] { '+' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int param1 = int.Parse(strs[0]);
int param2 = int.Parse(strs[1]);
int result = param1 + param2;
yourLabel.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: You are welcome @user3264955 . any more troubles, please tell me.

Comment: after searching some workaarounds (which i didn't have any luck on) param1 and param2 only take the first index of the array. so if i put "12+34" it only gets "1" and "3". it works though for 1 digit numbers xD

Comment: Hi, @user3264955, I tried it and it worked well. please check your code, if you use char instead of string? or other issues?

Comment: oops sorry for that. i was using the variable of my textbox instead of the split variable. anyway, thanks again. :D

Answer (score 4):

You can split the string on the plus sign:

```
string[] parts = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { '+', '-', '/', '*' });
```

Or equivalently (because the parameter to [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Split` is a [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) array):

```
string[] parts = textBox1.Text.Split('+', '-', '/', '*');
```

Comment: reading about split method. Thanks for your fast replies guys :D

Comment: You don't need the `new char[]`, since it's a `params` array, but you still need to figure out what the operator is somehow. Also, you might want to handle strings like `5*-2`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g please edit my answer and place an alternate syntax without `new char`. I would love to learn a new syntax ;-)

Comment: Cool. Thanks @p.s.w.g . Had no idea of this syntax.